# Iterate through each key and it's value, of a function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that I'm trying to loop through, with the purpose of amending those variables with a `", "` after them.

```
def create_merge(address, city, state_province, country, postal_code, contact, state):
    for key in locals().keys():
        for value in locals().values():
            print(key, value)
```

This ...kind of works, but not really. While it gives me a proper readout of all values in that def, it only shows `state` for the key.  I get why, because I'm looping through all values in the first key, before it moves to the second.

What I'd like to have is a loop that would produce, say:

```
address 123 My Address
city 
state_province Illinois
country USA
postal_code 12345
contact McGruff
state Illinois
```

And this, clearly just first lists the keys, then the values. How do I do one key and one value at a time?

```
for key in locals().keys():
    print (key)
for value in locals().values():
    print (value)
```

...`print (key, key.values())` doesn't work.

Nor

```
for key in locals().keys():
    print (key, locals().values())
```

I think I'm getting close, but just can't get it!  Thanks for any suggestions/advice.

Final note: I need to do this in a way where I can see if the `value` is NOT empty, and if not empty, amend the value with `", "` before the function continues.

Comment: Could you provide the variable you are trying to iterate through?  Do you have a dictionary like this, or are you looking to pass the variables into the function through another loop?
    location = {'address' : '123 My Address', 
'city' : None,
'state_province' 'Illinois',
'country' : 'USA',
'postal_code' : 12345, 
'contact' : 'McGruff', 
'state' : 'Illinois'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the keys and print out the key and the value of the key using the `.get` method.

```
for key in locals().keys():
    print(key, locals().get(key))
```

Alternatively, you could just use indexing to get the value.

```
for key in locals().keys():
    print(key, locals()[key])
```

Finally, you could also use `.items()` of dictionaries. (`.iteritems()` for Python 2.x)

```
for key, value in locals().items():
    print(key, value)
```

Make sure you instantiate `key` and `value` before you use these variables. Otherwise, you will change the items inside `locals()` while iterating and you will get an error.

Comment: I get "RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration` when doing those.  Edit: Aha! Your edit did the trick, looping through `items()`. :D

Answer (score 0):

While @VictorC's  `for key, value in locals().items()` worked, I found that this does too:

```
for key, value in zip(locals().keys(), locals().values()):
    print (key, value)
```

(Just noting this here for the record.  I'm still learning python, so I'm very open to someone commenting on the difference in `zip()` vs. looping through `items()` if they are bored).

Comment: I'm not sure about what the difference in performance is, but I do know that `locals().items()` returns the same result as `zip(locals().keys(), locals().values())`. My assumption is that `locals().items()` only requires iteration through `locals()` once, while the `zip` method will require two iterations, once to get the keys and once to get the values.